# How to Install ssl certificate in xampp server in ubuntu

Tags: ssl, subdomain

I haves domain.crt and domain.key, how can install in xampp server in Ubuntu os,can any one tell me the steps

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in httpd-vhost file.

Find this file, 
xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf

and add this to the bottom of the page.

DocumentRoot /your/project/root/folder
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

You will also need to enable vhost in httpd.conf
Add this line to httpd.conf file

~# Virtual hosts

Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf